# How to create a collection from res/values/arrays.xml?

Tags: android

How to create a collection from `res/values/`arrays.xml:

```
<resources>
<string-array name="select_dialog_items">
    <item>Start</item>
    <item>Stop</item>
    <item>Delete</item>
</string-array>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that `this` is your Activity...

```
String[] data = this.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.select_dialog_items);
```